# How can query string search a data using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Im using mongoose-paginate for my pagination and I want to add search for my project...
How can get query string search using mongoose node like these example...
(/allStudents?stdID=440033)

```
My code is:

router.get('/allStudents', async (req,res) => {

  const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit, 4) || 4;
  const page = parseInt(req.query.page, 10) || 1;

  const PAGE_SIZE = 10;
  const skip = (page - 1) * PAGE_SIZE;

  try {

     const students = await Student.paginate({}, {limit, page, skip}) 
        ||  await Student.find({ stdID:  req.query.stdID})

     return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        data: students
     })

 } catch (err) {
       console.log(err);
 }


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass your query as the first parameter according to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate#more-advanced-example):

```
const students = await Student
    .paginate(
        {stdID: req.query.stdID},
        {limit, page, skip}
    );
```

Comment: But If I have removed the query string it goes data:[]?

Comment: but Im removing the query string it contains nothing ( data:[] )

Comment: I can make 2 query for mongoose-paginate? How?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean :) Maybe post a new question where you describe your new problem in detail?